# Are AMI's incremental like an EBS snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that EBS snapshots are (or can be) incremental, and since an AMI is essentially a snapshot, is it also incremental?

I have been googling around for some time now, but I can't find an answer that suffices.

A side question for people that use AMI's in production; how do you deal with the disruptance creating AMI's makes? Or do you handle backups differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMIs use snapshots. They really aren't anything more than a snapshot or group of snapshots with a little bit of added metadata. The snapshots AMIs use are incremental like regular EBS snapshots, because indeed they are just regular EBS snapshots. You can even go into your list of snapshots and see the ones created by the AMI process.

> how do you deal with the disruptance creating AMI's makes?

What "disruptance creating AMIs" are you talking about? Are you talking about the reboot? You know you can create an AMI with "no reboot".

> Or do you handle backups differently?

AMIs aren't really for backups. I only create AMIs when I need to do something like move an instance to a different VPC or a different region or something. I use EBS snapshots for backups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark.

It's good to know AMI's aren't used for backups. So I should be making EBS snapshots in my backup plan, all right. 

What I'm still not 100% sure about is, can you effectively create the same machine from an EBS snapshot?